# If I copied some files from a hard disk with bad sectors without errors, are those files unaffected?

Tags: hard-drive-recovery, bad-sectors

Or do I have to find a backup?

It had thousands of reallocated sectors.

I ran `badblocks` on one partition but not others. Does that change the result?

I'm using Ubuntu. Some partitions are ntfs and some are ext4, if that matters.

**Edit:**

I believe the the bad sectors are because of it fell down to the floor for many times.

The first partition is a Ubuntu installation (for boot repair, or using Ubuntu on someone else's computer, etc), which has nothing important and I didn't use it for maybe at least a year. I didn't feel anything strange until one day I failed to boot a computer using it.

I ran `badblocks` on two partitions, and found thousands of errors mostly only on that partition. But it is very slow when reading some files on the second partition, which is why I'm concerned.

I didn't check other partitions yet because it becomes obvious I will replace this disk, and I'm afaid of making things worse by reading and writing for more times.

Comment: If you are asking if those files are corrupt, only you can answer that, by verifying if the files are not corrupt yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound Did you mean that, if the files are corrupt, it may return garbage data silently without reporting any errors? Then what are the ECC for? Only for correction, but I cannot know whether it is possibly corrupted?

Comment: ECC only works if corruption can be detected and correct.  A bad sector that isn't guaranteed.  You can detect corruption by comparing it to a known good copy.

Comment: @Ramhound Is there any technical informations about how it is likely undetectable and corrupted? I don't have known good copies for every file. And some files are from hundreds of old CD-ROMs I wanted to get rid of, and I really don't want to backup those again.

Comment: I don't know where your confusion is with my statements so I can't help.  There are soft sector failures and hard sector failures.  In the case of a soft sector failure, the HDD thinks the sector is bad, when it actually isn't.  In the case of a hard failure, no amount of attempts to trick the HDD, will make the sector good.  In a hard failure you normally have mechanical problems also.

Comment: @user23013: ECC detects *and* sometimes corrects errors. Undetected errors on modern drives are extremely rare to the point that they may as well never happen. The whole reason a bad sector exists is because the ECC detected corruption.

Answer (score -2):

If the files copied over successfully, without errors, it is highly unlikely that you will have problems with them. With that many sectors failing I would certainly prepare to replace that hard-drive before long, go ahead and start doing backups for an important documents or media just to be safe. Generally if a file is being copied from a corrupted sector of a disk it will error out as opposed to being problematic afterward.

Comment: This is only true if the HDD can detect the corruption.  There is a non-trivial chance that a HDD with this many bad sectors, would not know the sector was actually bad until the file couldn't be read.

Comment: It sometimes doesn't report any errors, but runs very slowly. I think at least it tried to recover some damaged data, but I'm not sure how much confidence I should have about the recovered result.

Comment: @user23013: The recovered result is 100% accurate.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq If you can expand it to an answer and maybe add some reference, I can accept your answer. (Preferably also whether `badblocks` will damage data or suppress further error reports, but I may post another question if you think that's irrelevant.)